# find beginning of a string inside an array of strings in php

Tags: php

I know we have the php in_array function

but I'm looking for a way to find values in an array of strings who beginning matches a specific string

for example find...

```
$search_string = '<div>1</div>';
```

in an array like this...

```
$array = (
    'sample'  => '<div>1</div><p>fish food</p>',
    'sample2' => '<div>2</div><p>swine</p>
);
```

does that make sense

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either loop on all lines of the array, and use `strpos` on each string ; a bit like this :

```
$search_string = '<div>1</div>';
$array = array(
    'sample'  => '<div>1</div><p>fish food</p>',
    'sample2' => '<div>2</div><p>swine</p>'
);

foreach ($array as $key => $string) {
  if (strpos($string, $search_string) === 0) {
    var_dump($key);
  }
}
```

Which will get you the key of the line that starts with your search string :

```
string 'sample' (length=6)
```

Or [preg_grep](http://php.net/preg_grep) might do the trick too :

> Returns the array consisting of the
>   elements of the input  array that
>   match the given pattern .

For instance :

```
$result = preg_grep('/^' . preg_quote($search_string, '/') . '/', $array);
var_dump($result);
```

*(Don't forget to use [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) ! )*

Will get you :

```
array
  'sample' => string '<div>1</div><p>fish food</p>' (length=28)
```

Note that, this way, you don't get the key, but only the content of the line.

Comment: I decided to go with strpos because I thought it woul be more efficient than a regular expression and I have a lot of control over the string

Answer (score 3):

Try [`preg_grep()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) or [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to find whether any string within the `$array` begins with the `$search_string` (basically an alternative [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) that would check beginning of the string), you could also use [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
array_reduce($array, function ($contains, $item) use ($search_string) {
    return $contains = $contains || (strpos($search_string, $item) === 0);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just cycle over your array and check with a regular expression, or strstr, or substr(...) == $search_string?

```
$res = "";
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  if(substr(0, strlen($search_string)-1, $value) == $search_string) {
    $res = $key;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yo Palantir, I'm really happy for you, Imma let you finish, but Ionut had one of the best answers of all time!

Comment: @Imagist, really? Are you referring to my answer on this question or is it another one?