# Check First 2 Digits Of All Values in an Array

Tags: php, arrays, function, for-loop, callback

I have an array_filter callback function that checks if digits are in an array like so:

```
$code = "22";
$orders = array_filter(
            $orders,
            function ($key) use($code) {
                return (in_array($code, $key['trans']));
            }
        );
```

But this is checking if the trans value has a digit that matches exactly 22, so it's limiting the results.

I'd like to display all trans value's that start with the $code (22) - I'd like to ignore using a for loop if possible, since it'll take longer to display the results.

What can I do instead?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to filter out all elements that don't start with `22`?

Comment: No - I want to filter elements that start with 2

Comment: Just an FYI - for (each) loops are generally faster than their array_* equivalents. http://www.levijackson.net/are-array_-functions-faster-than-loops/

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
return (in_array($code, $key['trans']));
```

to

```
return substr( $key['trans'], 0, strlen($code) ) == $code;
```

If `$key['trans']` is array, then we need to iterate it to search for `$code` inside it ([sandbox example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b15b1efbc939abebdad103295d3ce04d39a6c8d1)):

```
return count(array_filter($key['trans'],
  function ($key2) use($code) {
    return substr( $key2, 0, strlen($code) ) == $code;
  })) > 0;
```

P.S. I used `array_filter` for inner array because of this answers: [find beginning of a string inside an array of strings in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443891/find-beginning-of-a-string-inside-an-array-of-strings-in-php)

P.P.S. This is my one-line solution. As @waterloomatt mentioned in comments, simple `for` is faster than `array_filter`, so better to create a helper function to check if array has something inside that starts with what you need.

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: This would work if trans only had one value - sorry I should have specified this in my question. The trans has an array of values, so therefor substr() function wouldn't work here.

Comment: @alexel My bad. Updated my answer. Now better?